# Jquery How do I change +, - on expandable section

Tags: jquery

**(using jquery) I have the following function**

```
$(function() {
    $('tr.parent')
        .css("cursor","pointer")
        .attr("title","Click to expand/collapse")
        .click(function(){
            $(this).siblings('.child-'+this.id).toggle();
        });
    $('tr[@class^=child-]').hide().children('td');
});
```

**I have the following web page**

```
<table>
    <col style="width:40px;">
    <col style="width:80px;">
    <col style="width:150px;">
    <col style="width:40px;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th colspan="2">Name</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="parent" id="row123">
        <td>123</td>
        <td colspan="2">[+]Bill Gates</td>
        <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-row123">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>2007-01-02</td>
        <td>A short description</td>
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-row123">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>2007-02-03</td>
        <td>Another description</td>
        <td>45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-row123">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>2007-03-04</td>
        <td>More Stuff</td>
        <td>40</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="parent" id="row456">
        <td>456</td>
        <td colspan="2">[+]Bill Brasky</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-row456">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>2007-01-02</td>
        <td>A short description</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Desired Results:**

Change between the text with a '[+]' and '[-]' to the left of the expandable sections to indicate it can be expanded or compressed.

Comment: you do not have a [+] or a [-] in your code, where do you intend to place it at all ?

Comment: Ok I put it where it should be. This [+] should switch between [-] and [+] when clicked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this before your edit, and I still think it's valid. I changed your markup very slightly to put the `[+]` in its own cell eg:

```
<tr class="parent" id="row123">
    <td>[+]</td>           
    <td>123</td>
    <td colspan="2">Bill Gates</td>
    <td>100</td>
</tr>
```

Then your code becomes simply:

```
$('tr.parent')
    .css("cursor","pointer")
    .attr("title","Click to expand/collapse")
    .click(function(){
        var sibs = $(this).siblings('.child-'+this.id).toggle();
        var expanded = sibs.is(':visible');
        $(this).children('td').eq(0).text( expanded ? '[-]' : '[+]');
    });
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vxdq8/

If you *really* want the +/- inside the second cell, I suggest you wrap it in a span and change the relevant line above to:

```
$(this).children('td').eq(1).children('span').text( expanded ? '[-]' : '[+]');
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/8J8Vj/

Comment: Slight change (http://jsfiddle.net/Vxdq8/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/8J8Vj/1/) using `&minus;` instead of `-` which maintains the width of the character.

Comment: Thanks @cbuckley that *does* look better.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a simple html/text replace method:

http://jsfiddle.net/xBNGB/

I see you starting state is open.. so i changed the + to a - on load.

Change your script to this:

```
$(function() {
    $('tr.parent')
        .css("cursor","pointer")
        .attr("title","Click to expand/collapse")
        .click(function(){

            var children = $(this).siblings('.child-'+this.id);
            children.toggle();

            if (children.css('display')=='none')
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace('-','+'));
            else
                $(this).html($(this).html().replace('+','-'));
        });
    $('tr[@class^=child-]').hide().children('td');
});
```

Comment: This works **GREAT** until one of the texts inside the cell legitametly contains a plus or a dash! (ie, it doesnt work for long).

Comment: As far as I know the replace will only replace the first match, and not globally in the entire string.

Answer (score 1):

Two different approaches you could take:

1. Wrap the +/- text in a span, and then when the status of that item changes, use .find() to locate the span within the clicked element and change its contents.
2. Forget putting it as text, and include them as nicer-looking images as backgrounds of the element (with enough padding-left to accomodate). Then it's just a matter of toggling the element's class such that it shows the + or the - background image.

Comment: Could you demonstrate this somewhere (like jsfiddle) or point me some where I could view the code example. Thanks Greg

Comment: The methods you need are simple: `.find()` and `.text()` for option 1, or `.addClass()` with `.removeClass()` (might even be a way to do it with `.toggleClass()` although I find it fragile sometimes). Alas, no time to write a full sample right now. Maybe someone else will oblige in another answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('tr:first').append('<th></th>');

                $('tr.parent').append('<td>+</td>');

                $('tr.parent').css("cursor", "pointer").attr("title", "Click to expand/collapse").click(function () {
                    $(this).siblings('.child-' + this.id).is(':visible') ? $(this).find('td:last').text('+') : $(this).find('td:last').text('-');
                    $(this).siblings('.child-' + this.id).toggle();
                });

                $('tr[class^=child-]').hide();
            });


//Or  

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('tr:first').append('<th></th>');

            $('tr.parent').addClass('Expand').append('<td>+</td>');

            $('tr.parent').css("cursor", "pointer").attr("title", "Click to expand/collapse").click(function () {
                $(this).hasClass('Expand') ? $(this).removeClass('Expand').addClass('Compress').find('td:last').text('-') : $(this).removeClass('Compress').addClass('Expand').find('td:last').text('+');
                $(this).siblings('.child-' + this.id).toggle();
            });

            $('tr[class^=child-]').hide();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/NE4rK/